# Deleting folders in docker conatiner using python

Tags: python, django, docker

I have this function which deletes the given directory when row is being deleted in Django Admin. The row is successfully deleted when done on Django Admin but the directory still exists.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
import git, os, shutil

class DIR (models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=39)
    repository = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def get_dir_name(self):
        return os.path.join(settings.PLAYBOOK_DIR, self.repository)

    def rm_repository(self):
        DIR_NAME = self.get_dir_name()
        shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(DIR_NAME))

    def delete(self):
        self.rm_repository(self):
        super(DIR, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

But when I try it using shell, the directory and contents get deleted

```
$ docker exec -it <container> python manage.py shell

>>> import os, git, shutil
>>> DIR_NAME = '/opt/app/john'
>>> shutil.rmtree(DIR_NAME)
```

What is the difference between shell. There were no errors given, just not sure why doing it in Django Admin's `delete` doesn't work. While it is working when tested on python shell?

Comment: `import os os.remove(filename)`

Comment: @rkatkam not trying to delete just one file. Was trying to delete an entire directory

Answer (score 0):

Apparently function delete() is not for bulk delete.
Which what I was doing in Django Admin.